# How can I determine the site prefix of a SharePoint site via an API?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, site-collection, url, graph-api, managed-path

I use the SharePoint API to access a tenant SharePoint with a SharePoint REST API call that looks like `{site_prefix}/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl({path})/...` where `site_prefix` is usually something like `/sites/siteName` but I think that it can sometimes also be `/teams/siteName`. Given a `webUrl` of a driveItem, I was using a regular expression like `re.match(r"/sites/([^/]+)", webUrlPath).group()` and this usually works because most sites prefixes start with `/sites/`.

However, I've run into a tenant that does not have a prefix like this, but rather their own custom prefix, so their item's `webUrl` looks like `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/customname/`. I would like to know how to determine that the site prefix here is `customname` so that I can plug it into the SharePoint REST API call that I mentioned in the beginning. I assume that this has something to do with "Managed Paths", but I do not know how to find the managed paths programmatically. If necessary, I also have access to the Graph API.

I have considered just trying `/sites/([^/]+)`, `/teams/([^/]+)`, and as last resort `([^/]+)`, but I think this may not always work because (please correct if I'm wrong) the prefix may also  have multiple slashes making it hard to know where the prefix ends and path begins.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using? Why are you using hardcoded site URL? If you are calling any API from SharePoint pages, you can get the current site URL from page context.

Comment: @GaneshSanap I'm not the one using SP per se -- it's the customer/tenant and I am accessing information about their SP using the SP REST and Graph APIs. I'm not hardcoding any site URLs -- I'm trying to determine the site prefix of the site collection of a given drive item or site. There is no page context.

Answer (score 1):

It was simpler than I initially thought once I realized that I can get the `siteUrl` from any given drive item. I'm using the graph API to get the SharepointIds with `?$select=sharepointids` followed by parsing out the path with `urllib.parse.urlparse(result["sharepointIds"]["siteUrl"]).path` (Python). This is working so far, as I get `/sites/name` for most sites and `/customname` on the problem site.